# Finding a closed form expression for $\sum_{k=\frac {n+2} 2} ^n \binom n k$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-theorem

> Find a closed expression for $\displaystyle\sum_{k=\frac {n+2} 2} ^n \binom n k$,  $n$ is even.

My attempt:

$(1+1)^n = \displaystyle\sum_{k=0} ^ n \binom n k= \sum_{k=0} ^{\frac {n-2} 2}\binom n k + \binom n {\frac n 2} + \sum_{k=\frac {n+2} 2} ^n\binom n k$

From the identity $\binom n k = \binom n {n-k}$ we know that: $A=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0} ^{\frac {n-2} 2}\binom n k = \sum_{k=\frac {n+2} 2} ^n\binom n k$

So we have: $2^n = 2A + \binom n {\frac n 2} \Rightarrow A = 2^{n-1} - \frac 1 2 \binom n {\frac n 2}$

But I was told that something is missing in this approach, but I can't see what can be wrong here.

Comment: Did you check your answer for the simplest case, e.g. $n=2$ ?

Comment: It appears to be correct.

Comment: @lmsteffan: It yields the correct answer for $n=2$: the sum is $\binom22=1$, and $2^{2-1}-\frac12\binom21=2-1=1$.

Comment: @lmsteffan yeah the final answer is correct and I checked with several n's.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott so nothing is really missing here?

Comment: @kuhaku: It looks fine to me unless you were supposed to simplify the final expression in some way, and I see no useful way to do that. It’s the answer that I’d have obtained.

Comment: Yeah, can't find a fault either. Could it be some condition on $n$, like $n \ne 0$ ?

Comment: The title has the lower limit (n+2)/2, but you solved for A which has it (n-2)/2.